# CursorAdapter fails silently when retrieving data

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I'm trying to fetch the data stored using a custom CursorAdapter, but so far it is failing silently. It just loads a blank view and doesn't print anything.

Here is the onCreateView for the main fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.network_listview, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.network_listview);     

    aToken = getSherlockActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("token");
    aTokenSecret = getSherlockActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("token_secret");

    context = getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext();

    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(); 
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Const.CONSUMER_KEY);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Const.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    builder.setOAuthAccessToken(aToken);
    builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret((aTokenSecret));
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
    mTwitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

    mListAdapter =  getListAdapter(); 
    mListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter); 

    updateList();

    return view;
}
```

getListAdapter():

```
CursorAdapter getListAdapter() { 
    CursorAdapter ad = new TweetAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), null);
    return ad; 
}
```

TweetAdapter:

```
public class TweetAdapter extends CursorAdapter 
{
    private ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        private ImageView profileView;
        private TextView updated; 
        private ImageView favoriteIcon; 
        private TextView name; 
        private TextView message; 
        private TextView retweeted_by;

        private ViewHolder(View row)
        {
            profileView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.preview); 
            updated = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.updated);
            favoriteIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.favorite_icon);
            name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            message = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.message);
            retweeted_by = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.retweeted_by);
        }
    }

    public TweetAdapter(Context context, Cursor c){
        super(context, c, true);        
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
    {
     // this doesnt print out anything, even though there is data in the database
        String tweetText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Tweets.COL_TEXT_PLAIN));
        System.out.println("Tweet Text: " + tweetText);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_tweet, parent, false); 
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);

        return row; 
    }
}
```

updateList():

```
void updateList() 
{
    mCursor = getCursor();
    Cursor oldCursor = mListAdapter.swapCursor(mCursor);
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (oldCursor != null) {
            oldCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a `null` `Cursor` when constructing the `TweetAdapter` instance, so your adapter starts out with no data. Then `updateList()` replaces the adapter's `null` `Cursor` with whatever is in `mCursor` (which you do not show in the code you provided).

If `mCursor` is also `null`, then your code will end up either displaying no content (which is what you are seeing) or throwing an uncaught exception.

So, make sure you actually do a query that fills in the `mCursor` variable before calling `updateList()` .